# Range for vertical bar chart with google chart-wrapper

Tags: python, google-visualization

I've been trying to figure out how to use [google chart-wrapper](http://code.google.com/p/google-chartwrapper/) with my django application but I can't seem to find hardly any documentation on how to use it.  After playing around with it for awhile I got it to do most everything I want it to, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the range quite right.

For example, this url:

http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chxt=x&chd=t:2.0,1.0,192.0,1032.0,22.0,60.0,75.0,94.0,3.0,2.0,1.0,11.0,383.0,3.0,164.0,50.0,12.0,5.0,564.0,7671.0,115.0,331.0&chm=N%2A,000000,0,-1,11&chs=1000x300&cht=bvs&chtt=Failure+Types&chxl=0:|B16|B13|B10|C11|A10|A13|D04|D03|D02|B01|C09|B05|B04|B07|C01|C03|C04|C07|A02|A01|A06|A05

has several values above 100 (in the chd section of the url), but when it gets rendered it cuts anything above 100 off.

This is the code I used to create that url:

```
hist = {}
d = Defect.objects.all()

for defect in d:
     c = Failure.objects.filter(defect = defect).count()
     if c > 0:
          hist[defect.defcode] = c

m = VerticalBarStack(hist.values())
m.title("Failure Types")
m.size(1000,300)
m.marker('N*', 'black', 0, -1, 11)
m.axes('x')
m.axes.label(0, '|'.join(hist.keys()))
```

It seems logical that google chart-wrapper would allow me to write something along the lines of m.range(1000) or something similar to specify the range to show on the chart, but that doesn't work and I can't find any real documentation or detailed, complex enough examples to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add scaling for extended encoding.
I have added the required parameters, as below:
chds=0,2000

your final URL is:

http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chxt=x&chd=t:2.0,1.0,192.0,1032.0,22.0,60.0,75.0,94.0,3.0,2.0,1.0,11.0,383.0,3.0,164.0,50.0,12.0,5.0,564.0,7671.0,115.0,331.0&chm=N%2A,000000,0,-1,11&chs=500x500&cht=bvs&chds=0,2000&chtt=Failure+Types&chxl=0:|B16|B13|B10|C11|A10|A13|D04|D03|D02|B01|C09|B05|B04|B07|C01|C03|C04|C07|A02|A01|A06|A05